# Transaction "Revert" Error

Tags: solidity, remix

The error I get when trying to make ethertoDai() run is:

> { "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
> "code": -32000, "data": { "stack": "o: VM Exception while processing
> transaction: revert\n at Function.o.fromResults
> (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:6:120966)\n at e.exports
> (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:41:2269990)", "name": "o" } }

```
/// @title Kyber Network interface
interface KyberNetworkProxyInterface {
    function maxGasPrice() public view returns(uint);
    function getUserCapInWei(address user) public view returns(uint);
    function getUserCapInTokenWei(address user, ERC20 token) public view returns(uint);
    function enabled() public view returns(bool);
    function info(bytes32 id) public view returns(uint);

    function getExpectedRate(ERC20 src, ERC20 dest, uint srcQty) public view
        returns (uint expectedRate, uint slippageRate);

    function tradeWithHint(ERC20 src, uint srcAmount, ERC20 dest, address destAddress, uint maxDestAmount,
        uint minConversionRate, address walletId, bytes memory hint) public payable returns(uint);

    function swapEtherToToken(ERC20 token, uint minRate) public payable returns (uint);

    function swapTokenToEther(ERC20 token, uint tokenQty, uint minRate) public returns (uint);


}
contract Playground {

    address public daiAddress = 0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f;
    address public kyberAddress = 0x818E6FECD516Ecc3849DAf6845e3EC868087B755;
    address private ETH_ADDRESS = 0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee; 
    address public UniDaiAddress = 0x2a1530C4C41db0B0b2bB646CB5Eb1A67b7158667;

    constructor(){

    }

    function etherToDai(uint256 quantity) payable returns (uint256) { // Buy DAI on the KyberNet
        KyberNetworkProxyInterface KNPI = KyberNetworkProxyInterface(daiAddress);
        uint256 expectedRate;
        uint256 slippageRate;
        ERC20 daiToken = ERC20(daiAddress);
        (expectedRate, slippageRate) = KNPI.getExpectedRate(ERC20(ETH_ADDRESS), daiToken, quantity);
        uint256 received = KNPI.swapEtherToToken.value(quantity)(ERC20(daiAddress), slippageRate);
        require(daiToken.transfer(msg.sender, received));
        return received;
    }

    function () external payable  {

    }
}
```

What is the problem, and how am I supposed to debug an error like this?

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: Please share the code of `KyberNetworkProxyInterface`.

Comment: I tried to run it in the Remix tool after deployment (on mainnet fork)

Comment: Nevertheless, how do you call it (what input parameters do you pass)?

Comment: updated - I only pass "quantity" (uint265)

Comment: "how am I supposed to debug an error like this?" - start by getting rid of the last 3 lines and declaring the function as `view returns (uint expectedRate, uint slippageRate)`. Then, make sure that you can actually call this function from Remix. While you're at it, check the returned result on Remix and share it here with the rest of us.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that `KyberNetworkProxyInterface(daiAddress)` should be `KyberNetworkProxyInterface(kyberAddress)`. I mean, what exactly is the idea behind converting the DAI token into a KyberNetworkProxy???

Comment: Thank you I just fixed that. The output is  { "0": "uint256: expectedRate 320076140761407614076", "1": "uint256: slippageRate 310473856538565385653" }. However, the original code still does not work even after the KyberNetworkProxyInterface correction.

Comment: Please DON'T fix your question according to the answers that you receive, because it renders them obsolete!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, given:

```
address public daiAddress = 0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f;
address public kyberAddress = 0x818E6FECD516Ecc3849DAf6845e3EC868087B755;
```

You should probably change this:

```
KyberNetworkProxyInterface KNPI = KyberNetworkProxyInterface(daiAddress);
```

To this:

```
KyberNetworkProxyInterface KNPI = KyberNetworkProxyInterface(kyberAddress);
```

As it's not really clear why you are converting the ERC20 DAI token into a Kyber-Network proxy.

---

Another problem seems to be in:

```
uint256 received = KNPI.swapEtherToToken.value(quantity)(ERC20(daiAddress), slippageRate);
```

Where the second input argument should probably be `expectedRate` rather than `slippageRate`.

---

Another potential problem is the fact that your contract must own at least `quantity` wei ether.

One way to ensure this is by passing that value when you call the function.

And by "passing that value", I don't mean as an **input parameter to the function**, but as a **value to the transaction**.

Note that for consistency, the Kyber contract might be requiring that you also pass it as an input parameter to the function.

Comment: I'm able to get the output of  { "0": "uint256: expectedRate 320076140761407614076", "1": "uint256: slippageRate 310473856538565385653" } with this change, however, when I uncomment the last 3 lines I get the same error. I'm trying to convert my ETH into DAI over Kyber

Comment: @Raven: See updated answer.

Comment: I made that change, but I still get the same cryptic error =(

Comment: @Raven: See updated answer.

Comment: By passing a value, do you mean replacing quantity with "msg.value", and then change my function to function etherToDai() payable returns (uint256) ?

Now, it won't let me chose how much ether I want to send, and it only pays gas. And it still fails with the same error.

Comment: @Raven: "change my function to `function etherToDai() payable returns (uint256)`"??? That's exactly how it's defined in your question!

Comment: I just got rid of the "uint256 quantity" and replaced it with msg.value in the function I mean.

Comment: @Raven: As I mentioned in the answer, note that function `swapEtherToToken` might be requiring you to pass the amount both in the input parameter and in the transaction value (for consistency, in order to make sure you know what you're doing).